# Delete records if present in Elasticsearch - Python and get count of records deleted

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am new to python and elasticsearch.
I would have a list of ids fetched from a different index.
Would like to know how to delete multiple document ids if present in a current index using python. If there is a count which can be got or if it has to be counted separately using a variable?

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers

es = Elasticsearch()
index_name = es_index
doc_type = your_doc_type
ids = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

def generate_actions(ids):
    for i in ids:
        yield {
            '_op_type': 'delete',
            '_index': index_name,
            '_type': doc_type,
            '_id': i
        }


for success, info in helpers.parallel_bulk(client=es, actions=generate_actions(ids), thread_count=4):
    if not success: 
        print('Doc failed', info)
```

This the code im trying to use. Not sure about efficiency. If there are better ways please let me know

Python version = 3.8+
ElasticSearch version = 7.x

Answer (score 1):

Use api `delete_by_query` [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html), but no detailed records

```
es = Elasticsearch()
query = {
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": ids 
    }
  }
}
res = es.delete_by_query(index_name, query)
print(res)

{
  "took" : 64,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "total" : 3,
  "deleted" : 3,
  "batches" : 1,
  "version_conflicts" : 0,
  "noops" : 0,
  "retries" : {
    "bulk" : 0,
    "search" : 0
  },
  "throttled_millis" : 0,
  "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis" : 0,
  "failures" : [ ]
}
```

Comment: It is 65535, ```By default, Elasticsearch limits the terms query to a maximum of 65,536 terms. You can change this limit using the index.max_terms_count setting.```  and  link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/query-dsl-terms-query.html @Viv